# Serving caffe models

Tags: caffe, tensorflow-serving

How to Serving caffe models?
I'm doing a project on image classification using pre trained caffe model, I want to serve my model like TFServing,How to Serving caffe models?

Comment: Can you take a look at https://github.com/rayglover-ibm/serving-caffe which is about using TF serving for caffe models? Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.